# Locate and Replace

Tags: notepad++

I want locate and replace the variable to convert to image time, to make a macro

I have this 
`<variable varName="Icon1" trait="textcontent" category="&ns_flows;>`

I want replace for this 
`<variable varName="Icon1" trait="fileref" category="&ns_vars;">`

but... i have more lines

```
<variable varName="Icon1"
<variable varName="Icon2"
<variable varName="Icon3"
```

I want search `<variable varName="Icon[any number]"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, you forgot one `"` after the semicolon from &ns_flow - so it's not `category="&ns_flows;>`, but `category="&ns_flows;">`

Searching for
`<variable varName="Icon(\d+)" trait=.* category=.*>`

and replace with

`<variable varName="Icon\1" trait="fileref" category="&ns_vars;">`

should do the job. Make sure, Regex is enabled and this should replace all occurences from `Icon` + multiple digits. (\d+) is a Wildcard that matches multiple Digits (at least one). If you just want to replace the variables that have `trait="textcontent" category="&ns_flows;"` you could replace instead:

`<variable varName="Icon(\d+)" trait="textcontent" category="&ns_flows;>`

with

`<variable varName="Icon\1" trait="fileref" category="&ns_vars;">`

Comment: But i have variables with textcontent atribut,
`<variable varName="S" trait="textcontent" category="&ns_flows;"></variable>
      <variable varName="Z" trait="textcontent" category="&ns_flows;"></variable>
      <variable varName="img" trait="fileref" category="&ns_vars;"></variable>`

Comment: The regex should do the job

Comment: No, only ones have on name icon, i cant use [1-999]